# On Proving $A=B$ (For Sets)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, soft-question

Let $A,$ and $B$ be two sets. We have $A\subseteq B \land B\subseteq A \iff A=B.$ Is this by definition, or is there a proof for this? Intuitively, this makes sense to me. I mean, if we have $A=B,$ then $A,$ and $B$ have the same elements so $A\subseteq B \land B\subseteq A.$ I also intuitively see how $A\subseteq B \land B\subseteq A$ implies that $A=B.$ What I want to know is if this is just by definition, or if there is a proof of this.

Comment: $A\subseteq B \land B\subseteq A \iff A=B$ is a definition.

Comment: Extensionality axiom: if two sets have the same elements, they are equal.

Comment: This is an axiom.

Comment: Extensionality axiom as Mauro said, plus definition of $\subseteq,$ plus a (very short) proof.

Comment: @Fred That's not the definition. The definition of equality of sets is given by the extensionality axiom.

Comment: @Trebor That's not an axiom. It's close to the extensionality axiom, though.

Comment: It depends on what you take to be your axioms. For some axiomatization of sets it could be an axiom. For some other axiomatization it could be a theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By axiom of extensionality:

$(\forall x)(x\in A\iff x\in B)\implies A=B$

by definition:
$A\subseteq B\iff (\forall x)[(x\in A\implies x\in B)]$

Thus by logic:

$(A\subseteq B)\land (B\subseteq A)\iff (\forall x)[(x\in A\implies x\in B)\\
\land(x\in B\implies x\in A)]$

From which you get:

$x\in A\iff x\in B$

And the axiom of extensionality implies $A=B$.

Comment: Well it wasn't a duplicate when i answered.

Comment: For such a "probably usual" question, the first thing to do before answering is to look for duplicates.

Comment: Thank you, i shall keep that in mind.